# Accuracy assessment of unsupervised clustering - GEE

Tags: cluster-analysis, google-earth-engine, unsupervised-learning

I have clustered my map on the basis of NDVI values using an unsupervised approach. I don't have the labels. However, I do have the cluster IDs that were automatically assigned.

How do I assess the accuracy of my clustering approach (without labels)?

I have tried to computer silhouette score using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(clustering.select("ndvi"), clustering.select("clusters"))
```

Where `clustering.select("ndvi")` is the clustered NDVI map and `clustering.select("clusters")` contains the cluster IDs.

But it is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
```

How can I achieve the computation of accuracy assessment of unsupervised clustering?